# Re-order elements during formatting or serialization

Tags: xtext

I have a Xtext (2.27.0) grammar, which allows the user to define the *availability of features* for certain software revisions.

A file loks as follows:

```
since Windows95 {
  FeatureA       true
  FeatureC       true
  FeatureB       false
  AnotherFeature false
}
```

`FeatureA` etc. are cross-references to another file, where all features are defined.

The corresponding grammar is

```
SinceBlock:
  'since' version=ID
  '{'
    capabilities += Capability
  '}'
;

Capability:
  feature=[featureDescription::Feature] value=BoolLiteral
;
```

How and where would I implement an automatic reordering of the lines in the `since`-block?
E.g. during save I want the lines to be sorted lexicographical.

I have debugged formatter and serializer but could not find a place, where I could influence the order of the objects

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure whether it is possible but, the formatter gives you access to the AST meaning that you can retrieve the EList<Capability> from the since block and sort it by means of Collections.sort. I'm not aware if this would have not intended side effects but perhaps it's worth a try ...

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález Tried that, but sorting the ELists (in the formatter) does not change anything. Maybe someone else will come up with another idea.